# Custom JComponent disappears when I use KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, jlayeredpane

for a while I've been struggling to move my custom SpriteComponent on a panel. Here is the code for the class:

```
    public class SpriteComponent extends JComponent
{
    private int x = 0;
    private BufferedImage sprite;
    private int y = 0;//declare instance fields
    public SpriteComponent(){
        try{
            sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Sprite.png"));
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
    public void moveR()
    {
        x += 64;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveL()
    {
        x -= 64;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveU()
    {
        y += 64;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveD()
    {
        y -= 64;
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)//overload paintComponent method
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(sprite,x,y,null);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if(sprite==null) return new Dimension(64,64);
        else return new Dimension(sprite.getWidth(null),sprite.getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

I want it to move on a panel with an image behind it. I tried using JLayeredPane and even creating my own custom panel, but when I add the sprite to the panel, it disappears when I press an arrow key. It works in a regular panel though...

Here is the code for the listener and UI:

```
public class Engine
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
        JPanel mappanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel invisible = new JPanel();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 750));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(lpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 1110, 550);
        mappanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Images/map.png")));
        mappanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1110, 550);
        mappanel.setOpaque(true);
        invisible.setBounds(0, 0, 1110, 550);
        invisible.setOpaque(false);
        final SpriteComponent s = new SpriteComponent();
        invisible.add(s);
        lpane.add(mappanel, new Integer(0), 0);
        lpane.add(invisible, new Integer(1), 0);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Pokemon");

    JPanel pokemonlist = new JPanel();
    pokemonlist.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,6));
    frame.add(pokemonlist, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Font g = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 15);
    mappanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new MatteBorder(15,15,15,15,new ImageIcon(new ImgUtils().scaleImage(15,15,"Images/Pokeball.png"))), "Map",0,0,g,Color.BLUE));
    pokemonlist.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new MatteBorder(15,15,15,15,new ImageIcon(new ImgUtils().scaleImage(15,15,"Images/Pokeball.png"))), "Pokemon List",0,0,g,Color.BLUE));

    class KeyPressListener implements KeyListener//inner class KeyPressListener implements interface KeyListener
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int x = e.getKeyCode();
            if (x==KeyEvent.VK_UP) s.moveU();
            if (x==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) s.moveR();
            if (x==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) s.moveL();
            if (x==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) s.moveD();
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {}

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {}
    }
    KeyPressListener kpl = new KeyPressListener();
    frame.addKeyListener(kpl);
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Don't use a KeyListener, but rather use Key Bindings (Google the tutorial). 2) You can avoid use of a JLayeredPane by simply drawing the background BufferedImage in the SpriteComponent's `paintComponent` method at [0, 0], as long as you do this before drawing your sprite.

Comment: Thanks so much! I painted the map in SpriteComponent like you suggested and it finally worked!